# Prevent and/or undo cell edit

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a macro for an Excel spreadsheet. I have it close to what I need it to do, but I've run into some trouble with it. I need the spreadsheet to prevent editing of cells that have values by clicking on the cell (this part works), but I also need the sheet to, if the cell is edited just by typing, either prevent the cell from being edited at all or undo that change and replace the new value with the original one.

For example, if I type in "Test" to one cell and try to type in "Test2" afterwards, I want the first value to remain the same. I also want it to do this within the same cell, not by copying the value into the cell next to it like it does now, but if needed I still want to be able to delete these rows or columns.

I've done this before, but I no longer have access to the spreadsheet, and I actually won't have access to the spreadsheet I'm currently making once I have it done, so I'm trying to make it work as intended just as it is for users to open and use.

This is the code I have so far:

```vb
Dim cng As String
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Handles disable features
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:Z102")) Is Nothing Then
            Cancel = True 'Prevent going into Edit Mode to change cell values
                If Target = vbNullString Then
                    Cancel = False
                Else
                    Cancel = True
                    cng = Target.Value
                End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:Z102")) Is Nothing Then
        cng = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Target.Value
        Target.Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below uses the `Locked` property to  allow or disallow editing.  When the user enters something in an unlocked cell it will be locked thereafter, and if he enters something in a locked cell the change will be rolled back. To ensure that filled cells are locked at the outset all non-empty cells within the designated range are locked when the sheet is activated.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const TriggerRange  As String = "A2:Z102"

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' 101
    
    Dim Arr         As Variant              ' TriggerRange.Value
    Dim Rr          As Long                 ' TriggerRange.Row
    Dim Cr          As Long                 ' TriggerRange.Column
    Dim R           As Long                 ' loop counter: rows
    Dim C           As Long                 ' loop counter: columns
    
    With Range(TriggerRange)
        Arr = .Value
        Rr = .Row - 1
        Cr = .Column - 1
    End With
    
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            Cells(R + Rr, C + Cr).Locked = Not IsEmpty(Arr(R, C))
        Next C
    Next R
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 101
    
    With Target
        If .Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range(TriggerRange)) Is Nothing Then
                If .Locked Then
                    MsgBox "This cell is locked. It may not be modfied." & vbCr & _
                           "Your change will be rolled back.", _
                           vbInformation, "Modification not permitted"
                    With Application
                        .EnableEvents = False
                        .Undo
                        .EnableEvents = True
                    End With
                Else
                    .Locked = Not IsEmpty(.Value)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

There are two peculiarities to the system. One is the one you already designated: The user can paste to or delete several cells at once. To take proper effect the Activate procedure has to run thereafter. The other is that you can cause a cell to be locked invisibly by entering a space (or other invisible character) in it.

Comment: This is working great for rolling back the changes, thank you!! But I'm having a problem with it rolling back a change to a blank cell if the cell is originally blank when the user goes to put in a value. Is there a good way to get around that issue and only undo a change if the cell already had a value, not if it was blank?

Comment: If you want to use the above system you would need to be selective about which cells are locked on Activate and remove the `Else: Locked = Not IsEmpty(.Value)` so that a previously unlocked cell can be edited. For the former, why don't you run the code before you release the worksheet for use but don't include it in the user's copy?

Comment: I'm actually not really 100% clear on what the spreadsheet is going to be used for, just what features are wanted for it. And the last time I worked on something like this was well over a year ago and for a different company. You mentioned being selective about which cells are locked on Activate. Any tips on that?

Comment: The code I wrote locks all cells that aren't blank. If there are cells that are not blank but should not be locked they must be identified by this procedure and their Locked property set accordingly.